# Suppress FastCGI PHP's session_start error in webserver logs when continuing session

Tags: php, session, webserver

I'm using PHP sessions to keep track of info that needs to be persistent between some pages. I call `session_start()` at the top of those pages, and my `$_SESSION` data magically gets saved! Yay! (Well, it's not real magic, but hey, much better than client-side cookies...)

However, my nginx logs are getting polluted with tons of these messages:

```
[error] 1105#0: *238 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
```

What should I do about this? I'd defintely prefer the error not being reported as such; [it's a session continuation and hence should not be even considered an error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), right? Or am I totally abusing `session_start()` somehow and my kind webserver is just giving me a gentle hint?

## Edit:

I call `session_start()` for the submit.php page that is the form submission action (because it needs access to the session data), and once it's done I then include the php page that creates new pages (which also calls `session_start()` for the same reason, and because it's genuinely needed when you are starting a new session). I'd really like to keep that functionality separate. At the moment, submit.php is getting most of it's data from `$_POST` but a little bit from `$_SESSION`, and I'd rather not put the sensitive session information on the client side.

Comment: It means `session_start` is being called more than once _in the same request_. Solution: don't do that.

Comment: Ah. Well that's pretty inconvenient in my particular circumstances! See edit above.

Comment: Your particular circumstances sound entirely standard.

Comment: So ... what's the solution? Surely everyone can't be calling `start_session()` twice if it returns errors?

Comment: Great, that solved it. The trouble is, I generally take my cues from the php.net manual as linked in the question, and if the manual says that `session_start()` resumes a session, I do not expect it to throw an error when it does!

Comment: That's because you're still misinterpreting what that means. To get that error you are resuming/starting the session once, and at least once more after that _in the same request_. Resume does not mean "start a session if it's not already started."